# ImportError: cannot import name 'signature'

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to import the package of recmetrics and I have done all the actions mentioned in other posts but it does not work.
The code is as follows

```
import recmetrics
```

and the error is

```
ImportErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-> in <module>
      5 import numpy as np
      6 from funcsigs import signature
----> 7 import recmetrics

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/recmetrics/__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from .plots import long_tail_plot, mark_plot, mapk_plot, coverage_plot, class_separation_plot, roc_plot, precision_recall_plot
      2 from .metrics import mark, coverage, personalization, intra_list_similarity, rmse, mse, make_confusion_matrix, recommender_precision, recommender_recall

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/recmetrics/plots.py in <module>
      5 from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
      6 from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc, precision_recall_curve, average_precision_score
----> 7 from sklearn.utils.fixes import signature
  
ImportError: cannot import name 'signature'
```

I have tried the following steps:

```
!pip freeze | grep recmetrics
recmetrics==0.0.12
```

First I tried :

```
from sklearn.utils.fixes import signature
```

Then I tried This :

```
from funcsigs import signature
```

Non of them works could you please let me know why it does not work. The python version which I am using is 3.6.10 |Anaconda.

I am using Amazonsage maker and I am wondering how I can SSHing in `~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/sitepackages/recmetrics/__init__.py`
to change `from sklearn.utils.fixes import signature` to `from funcsigs import signature`

Comment: Please show the complete backtrace of the error. What module is attempting to import `signature`…?

Comment: I have updated the error

Answer (score 2):

From: https://github.com/statisticianinstilettos/recmetrics/issues/4

> I had to manually change in the `plots.py`
> Instead of `from sklearn.utils.fixes import signature` use `from funcsigs import signature`

Comment: As you see in the code I tried to get " from funcsigs import signature " but it did not work.maybe i do not know how can I change it in plot.py, can you let me know how I can change in plot.py?

Comment: You need to make the change in here: `~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/recmetrics/plots.py`

Comment: could you please help me how i can access to this because i am writing in sage maker

Comment: If you mean amazon sagemaker, I will take that as you are using a shell. 

`cd ~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/recmetrics` open the file with any editor and make the change.

Comment: yes I mean amazon sagemaker but We cannot access SSH-ing into SageMaker notebook instances,because there is not public IP. can you tell me which editor i should use to open the file when I can not access SSH